# Can a SyncAdapter still function when the ARC application is closed?

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I have an android application that keeps its local database current using a SyncAdapter.

The SyncAdapter is a basic implementation with a Stub Authenticator, and Stub Content Provider.

The application does sync while open on a chromebook via ARC, but once the application is closed it does not sync until the application is opened again.

Is it possible to have the sync adapter run while the application is closed using ARC?